# Overlay nd array at different locations in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose I have an 3d array with the size of (100,100,100), I would like to overlay or copy this array centered at various points (with the range of 0-100 in all directions) in space and the resulting 3d array has a size of (100,100,100).  Any point near the edges of the array will be concatenated to maintain the resulting size of the array

I wrote this manually, by finding the range of the array index and coping it over but I suspect there is a easier way.

arr1.shape
(100, 100, 100)

point[0] = [5.5, 45.32, 35.0]
...
point[n] = [85.0, 15,2, 90.1]

arr2 = np.zeros((100,100,100),float)
for each point I will mannualy find and copy over
arr2[minx:maxx,miny:maxy,minz,maxz] = arr1[minx:maxx,miny:maxy,minz,maxz]
where min and max are index of the arrays.

Yes I am trying to convolve this kernel to the points.  I looked into numpy.convolve but don't know how I would go about doing it with scipy.

Comment: and also please define "space"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do a convolution. Does [scipy.ndimage.convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve) work for you?

Comment: I am trying to convolve but couldn't get it to work so ended up manually looping over and adding the pixels manually.